# Proxy front-end HTTP calls in development

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, proxy, elm

I' building a small website. The back-end is written in **Kotlin** and uses [Spring boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot), and the front-end is built in [Elm](https://guide.elm-lang.org).

The generated javascript app will be served statically by my back-end on deployment.

For development, I currently work as such :

- Serve my spring boot application on **localhost:8080**
- Serve my Elm app on b using [create-elm-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-elm-app)

The main reason is that create-elm-app allows for **hot-compilation and hot-reload of the Elm app**, which makes it very convenient.

**The problem with this is that I have to set up all my elm http calls against another port locally, which means I have to alter the code for production.**

Ideally, I'd like to:

- Either have live-recompilation of elm code that changes ( I used chokidar in node, but didn't find a direct java alternative) coupled to a spring boot hot reload
- Have create-elm-app redirect my API calls
- Or auto-proxy all my calls to another location via a third party

Does anyone have experience with this? What setup would you recommend?

Cheers,

Comment: Stack Overflow just forced me to use the word proxy, which actually seems to lead me to a possible answer : https://github.com/halfzebra/create-elm-app/blob/master/template/README.md#setting-up-api-proxy. Let me dig further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, using the word proxy did help!

It seems that the `create-elm-app` documentation already expects this use case. You can read more [about it here](https://github.com/halfzebra/create-elm-app/blob/master/template/README.md#setting-up-api-proxy).

Basically what needs to be done is:

- Create a `elmapp.config.js` file at the root of the elm project, with the following content (in my case, you can adapt):

```
module.exports = {
    proxy: "http://localhost:8080",
}
```

Then, in your elm code, use absolute URLs. For example :

```
makeCreateGameUrl : Model -> String
makeCreateGameUrl model =
    absolute
        [ "game" ]
        [ string "players" (joinListOfStrings model.newPlayerNames) ]
```

After this, your API calls will be directly redirected to your backend.